# Processing Coffeescript code in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

How can i process a coffeescript code directly into javascript in node.js ?

maybe i could use the coffee compiler using child_process.exec/spawn/fork but is there a direct way ? like loading a library (that ships with the coffee package when it's installed with npm) and passing code to it, that returns the compiled code directly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `npm install coffee-script` and then just put `var coffee = require('coffee-script');` to get access to the `coffee.compile` function which will do what you want.

Comment: Indeed; also, doing `require('coffee-script');` will register the `.coffee` file extension, so you will then be able to `require` CoffeeScript files.

Answer (score -1):

did you have a look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#template-engines)? 
It supports coffeekup template engine too.